multicast flooding limits throughput?
My group's R&D lab has an Arista 10G switch, DCS-7020SR-24C2. This switch is NOT configured for IGMP snooping. I can see that it is flooding all multicast to all ports.
I run an experiment where host A sends on multicast group 1 at close to 1 gbps. Host B subscribes to that multicast and also publishes its own multicast stream on group 2 at close to 1 gbps.
Host B's sending on group 2 interferes with its ability to keep up with receiving group 1.
This would make sense if the switch took multicast data received over host B's port and turned it around, sending it back out to host B. But I don't think switches do that. If you send out multicast, the switch should not be reflecting it back to you, even if you are subscribing to it. (In this case, host B is not subscribed to the group it is sending.)
All that said, I could still imagine that having almost 20 gbps of multicast data on the switch's backplane configured for flooding could cause problems. Does this make sense?
Also, is there any way to use "snmpwalk" to get a drop counter related to this?
Finally, I'm assuming that enabling IGMP snooping (and querier) will allow a host to send and receive multicast (on different groups) at close to 10G. True?

if the switch took multicast data received over host B's port and turned it around, sending it back out to host B - a switch must never do that, as it would mean multicast between two switches would circle forever, causing a storm. And it's easily testable, as is the effect of IGMP snooping.
